# What is Java written in?

Tags: java, jvm

What language is Sun's `JVM` written in?

Comment: possible duplicate of [In which language are the Java compiler, JVM and Java written?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1220914/in-which-language-are-the-java-compiler-jvm-and-java-written). This is older, but it is a subset and has less votes.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Sun actually has multiple JVMs. The [HotSpot JVM](http://OpenJDK.Java.Net/groups/hotspot/) is written largely in C++, because HotSpot is heavily based on the [Animorphic Smalltalk VM](http://Strongtalk.Org/) which is [written in C++](http://Code.Google.Com/p/strongtalk/source/browse/#svn/trunk/vm).

More interesting than HotSpot is IMHO the [Maxine Research VM](http://Research.Sun.Com/projects/maxine/), which is [written (almost) completely in Java](http://Kenai.Com/projects/maxine/sources/maxine/show).

Comment: "Low-church C++" would be a more accurate way of describing it.

Comment: Maxine will be definitely such a great thing, when it'll be ready!

Comment: Well, it's a research project. By definition, it'll never be ready.

Answer (score 25):

Strictly speaking, C++ (the JVM code does make use of C++ OO facilities).

Comment: the most logical answer, 100% agree with you

Answer (score 9):

You can find out for yourself at: http://www.sun.com/software/opensource/java/.

Answer (score 5):

C.

Sun's not a Java shop; it's a C shop.  That's what Solaris is written in.

Comment: It should be noted that nearly all the Java standard libraries however are written in Java.

Comment: Absolutely correct, of course, but the question was about the JVM itself.

Comment: At a guess, the C source includes some ASM - conditionally compiled on certain mainstream architectures.

Comment: Also: Sun's a big company. Parts of it will be a 'C shop', other parts will be writing in Java, or in shell, or Perl, or whatever. Solaris is written in C largely because when they got SysV from AT&T it was in C.

Comment: Still, a large part of the JVM is written in C.  (Or, was when I last looked at it.)

Comment: slim: The interpreters are written in an assembly language-like way in C++ (the C++ generates machine code).

Comment: Some of the libraries are written in C, some date back to before Java. Most of the libraries are Java. HotSpot is low-church C++, not C.

Comment: Silly response.  They were supposed to jump in the time machine and suggest Java for implementing Unix in 1970?  They were supposed to rewrite their Solaris in Java?  There have been a few Java OS's written, none targeting servers like Solaris does.