# Pointers are replaced with what in Java?

Tags: java, pointers

I read that pointers are not available in Java. But "This" pointer in C++ is replaced by "This" Keyword. So can someone explain about dynamic memory allocation and replacement for pointers in java

Comment: Although the question has been closed as non constructive... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8080617/why-doesnt-java-have-pointers/8080709#8080709

Comment: Read it where? According to the [JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.3) they are available: "The reference values (often just references) are pointers to these objects, and a special null reference, which refers to no object." There is also `NullPointerException` to consider.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are no pointers in java. Java works with references.

There is no concept of dynamic memory allocation in java. And hence there is no alternative of `malloc/calloc` in java. The JVM takes care of creating and releasing the memory for objects. As JVM has built in functionality of garbage collection hence no alternative to `free` is also provided.

Comment: So , you mean no "free" keyword in JAVA, am I right

Comment: @DaleSteyn No there is no free keyword in java, supporting link : http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/_keywords.html

Comment: Could you please giv info about passing objects in java. How is it done???

Comment: Ofcourse there is dynamic memory allocation in Java, using the `new` keyword. You just don't have to explicitly free dynamically allocated memory, because the garbage collector does that automatically for you.

Answer (score 3):

Internally a reference to an object is implemented as a pointer.. There is an anonymous inner class in java which you can use as a substitute for function pointer.

> 2.2.9 No More Pointers
>
> Most studies agree that pointers are one of the primary features that
>   enable programmers to inject bugs into their code. Given that
>   structures are gone, and arrays and strings are objects, the need for
>   pointers to these constructs goes away. Thus, Java has no pointer data
>   types. Any task that would require arrays, structures, and pointers in
>   C can be more easily and reliably performed by declaring objects and
>   arrays of objects. Instead of complex pointer manipulation on array
>   pointers, you access arrays by their arithmetic indices. The Java
>   run-time system checks all array indexing to ensure indices are within
>   the bounds of the array.

Check out this [Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8080617/why-doesnt-java-have-pointers)

Answer (score 2):

The "replacement" of unmanaged pointer in Java is a managed reference .

Take a look at [this](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/141834/how-is-a-java-reference-different-from-a-c-pointer) answer in programmers forum for the differences between the two .

Answer (score 2):

Java's references aren't pointers. You can't do pointer arithmetic with references in Java.

You can read a comprehensive analysis by Erik Demain [here](http://erikdemaine.org/papers/CPE98/paper.pdf): `C to Java: Converting Pointers into References`.

Answer (score 1):

Java does use pointers. It's just handled for you, as *"Object References*". So for example:

```
String str = new String("efi");

// str is NOT the string object.
// It is a reference to the String object.
```

The difference is, Java does this for you and doesn't let you do it yourself. *C++* allows you to manage them.

Answer (score 1):

```
Nothing. Java does not have a concept that is equivalent to Pointers.
```

Comment: So objects are not passed. Only there reference is indicated or passed as parameters. is it?

Answer (score 1):

Java uses reference to do initialization, setting or getting variables etc..
In C++ pointers are basically reference to the memory of that variable. So here each declaration is reference in java which is equivalent to pointer in c++, but internally handled by JVM not by programmer. Java internally handles this, we nothing have pointers like c++ in front.