# link executable to codeblocks

Tags: java, c, linker, codeblocks

I have a Code::Blocks project and the final executable is all that matters. It's written in C, but there is also a task that I cannot write in that language, so I'm doing it in Java.

My dilemma is how to link the java executable to my CodeBlocks binary? Copying the binary content obviously doesn't work.

That task is about sending emails, which has troubled me in C.

Comment: Have you tried JNI? You can call your c library functions from the java code and can add the new task in java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can send emails in C, using libcurl, which is a network library. You can DuckDuckGo about libcurl emails and find some code.

P.S: The JVM is written in C, so why should it be impossible to send emails in C ?

Comment: actually i think the jvm is C++

Comment: According to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1220914/in-which-language-are-the-java-compiler-jvm-and-java-written), the "bootstrap" java compiler was written in C, then re-implemented in Java, and the runtime is written in C. C or C++, it doesn't matter, my point is still valid.