# maximum security function to find MIN in array

Tags: c, arrays, function, security, memory

I was in an interview a few days ago and i got the following demand:

write a library function to find the MIN element of an array. MAKE IT AS SECURE AS POSSIBLE.
alright, so it was obvious that the accent there was on the security. The language is C, the company is in the embedded field. I later asked the interviewer if they can at least explain to me what is the case here because I was truly curious to learn, but he wasn't very talkative... So, I turned google upside down, but I did not find specifically a solution to this request.  I am fairly new to C. 
What are the security flaws that can occur here?
What are the red flags? 
I know that we should watch for array boundaries because overflowing it will cause memory issues and we could easily write/read from random memory. But aside of that, what should i look for?
Any feedback would be extremely useful! Thanks a bunch!

Comment: Its not exactly *security*, but I'd consider thread safety:  What happens if the function is called simultaneously from multiple threads?  If one thread attempts to alter the array while another thread is searching for the MIN element?  Do you have mutexs and locking in place?

Comment: "secure" and "array" are mutually exclusive in C. So my guess is this was a discussion question, not a coding question.

Answer (score 2):

There are really only two ways to search an array in C. Either you are explicitly told how many elements exist in the array, or there is some sort of value that you can check for to indicate end-of-array (like `'\0'` for strings).

If the first case is being used then and we have an array of `int`s, for example, then this:

```
int minInt(int array[],size_t num_elements){
  if(array==NULL || num_elements==0)
    return -1;
  size_t i;
  int min = array[0];
  for(i = 1; i < num_elements; ++i)
    if(array[i] < min)
      min = array[i];
  return min;
}
```

Is a good solution. If we're using the second case, and we have an array `char`s in the form of a C string, for example, and `'\0'` represents end-of-array, then perhaps this:

```
char minChar(char array[]){
  if(array == NULL)
    return -1;
  size_t i;
  char min = array[0];
  for(i = 0; array[i] != '\0'; ++i)
    if(array[i] < min)
      min = array[i];
  return min;
}
```

...would be a good response. It depends a lot on the specifics of the system, and the second case is only safe if you can be certain that the stop value is not missing.

Comment: @Willis A. Hershey  -1 is a valid integer value. It may not be used as a return value in case when an array is empty.

Comment: Fair. Good point. It depends on what the calling function expects. And I fixed the bounds check thanks for the heads-up

Comment: In both cases, code could return the address of the minimum and then return `NULL` when in degenerate cases.

Comment: Apologies. Fixed it

Comment: Thanks! This makes sense. As per usual, i froze and i i started digging in my mind to see where is the "catch". I guess there ins't a catch at all... just C specific things that i should know.

Answer (score 0):

There are two aspects to take into account:

- Memory Management
- Concurrency

---

### Memory Management

As you mentioned you are using C, which is a low-level language, functions can easily mess-up and access wrong memory locations, specially when there are many pointers passing around. So it is always good to make sure what are the boundaries of the array you are accessing, and enforce some rules to avoid passing them.

Some security attacks may happen when the attacker alters the parameters so that the function may return data from memory location outside the array! repeat the process multiple times with different altered parameters and the data in the memory is leaked!

---

### Concurrency

This only applies when you know there are multiple threads are running on the same program, then you might want to have a critical section that **locks** the array your function is using it.

---

I believe most of the functions you will find online do the job securely, perhaps your interviewer just wanted you to discuss with him the threats and attacks that might take place, and how are you aware about them.

Comment: I suppose this was the case also. I appreciate your feedback! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Security is most valuable feature we need to cover in our code, and in order to rich this level most of the time we need to pick a secure environment like Java, but in some case (especially in the embedded field) we need to handle the security manner manually. in the low level programming (the c-programming) there are two most common security issue:
Buffer overflow, and double free attack.
The buffer overflow is when the user try to enter an amount of data out of supported range (briefly) so to avoid this malicious security you need to cover as much as possible the edge case and prevent as creative the most "weird" scenario :).

```
char the_array[100];
```

taking the previous declaration the_array is work fine until the user/function decide to enter more then 100 character then you will be lucky if you avoid program crashing. so handling as much as possible edge case and be creative of reading real life scenario you can avoid this issues and there are a lot of techniques helps you.
The double free attack: this is the case when accidentally frees a pointer two times when you have re-initialize the pointer with a new memory address.

```
char *ptr;
ptr = malloc(10 * sizeof(*ptr));
/* Doing stuff */
free(ptr);
```

This is a sample dynamic allocation for pointer, in order to escape double free attack you need to set the ptr to null.

```
free(ptr);
ptr = NULL;
```

assuming you have a great knowledge about the C-programming, you need to avoid as much as possible the double free and nullify the pointer after each use. and there is a great tool helping debugging memory in C, try to use `Valgrind` in each run or test of you program it helps to track memory leak, double free, uninitialized variable ...

Comment: Ooops my bad, what about content?

Comment: Content --> Do not agree with "we need to pick a secure environment like Java".  Each language has its merits/liabilities.

Comment: I mean Java could be safer that typically run in protected environment (VM)

Comment: Would you expect the security of Java to exceed the VM?  At least in one case the [JVM is written in C](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1220931/2410359).

Comment: i knew about the buffer overflow issue, but the double free'd pointer is a new concept to me! Looks really interesting, i will definitely check it out. Thank you!